# Setting up users for ubuntu for ssh connection

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, permissions, sudo

I have created a new Ubuntu server and in root user, I created a new user. The steps I followed:

```
sudo adduser tom

sudo su - tom
mkdir .ssh
chmod 700 .ssh
touch .ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
nano .ssh/authorized_keys    // paste public key
```

It seems okay and I can login as `tom@example.com`. However when I logged in as Tom, it asks for permission and when I sudo something it asks for password, and I don't have a password for him so I use my root password, so it warns:

> [sudo] password for tom:
>   tom is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.

From my root user, I tried adding tom in `visudo` as

```
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
tom     ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

but this didn't change anything.

What is the proper way of this setup so Tom has permission to run stuff and the only password asked to him is his ssh password? Tom should run stuff like `sudo npm install` or `sudo composer install` with his ssh password and maybe he shouldn't even know root password

What am I missing here?

Comment: "it asks for password, and I don't have a password for him" ... "Tom should run stuff ... with his ssh password" Does the `tom` user have a password or not? Add the output of `sudo -l` when run as `tom`, please.

Comment: I would hope the 'tom' account has a password configured, however it sounds like the goal is to allow someone to use a SSH private key to connect to the host and run commands as root without knowing the password to the account.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Based on a second reading, if you still want the password prompted for Tom to use sudo, you would want:

```
tom    ALL = ALL: ALL
```

If you want tom to be able to run sudo without a password at all, use the below answer.

---

I believe you would want the line to be:

```
tom    ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Explanation:

`tom` is the user this line applies to, the first `ALL` is which hosts this applies to, `NOPASSWD` is a tag that specifies a password is not required, and the final `ALL` specifies what commands tom can run via sudo.

Note that if you want to restrict what commands (or even combinations of commands & arguments), you can replace the second `ALL`. For example:

```
tom    ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/kill, /usr/bin/lprm
```

See the [Sudoers man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers) and an [alternative man page](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html) with additional examples about 80% down the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following from root, or with `sudo` from your main user:

```
usermod -aG sudo tom
```

This will add your user tom to the 'sudo' group and thats all what should be needed. Since this makes changes to the `/etc/sudoers` file unnecessary you can revert your changes there, unless you want to remove the security layer of asking for a password for `sudo` commands. If you want this you should use the line (as stated by [@JasonRush](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/409078) in his answer) in your `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
tom    ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL
```

If you want however the usual way of having a password request for `sudo` command you should leave the `/etc/sudoers` file alone and simply add the user to the 'sudo' group. Then you only have to change `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` accordingly to not allow password logins.

Usually Ubuntu is set up that way that a usual user should be in some essential groups. You can check in which groups your main user is in by typing `groups` in terminal.

This is what it shows for me but your output might differ from that:

```
$ groups
<users-own-group> adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

A normal user which should not have extensive permissions should be at least in `cdrom, plugdev, lpadmin`. But since you're creating a sudo user (at least  it appears to me you want that) you should add your user to the groups accordingly. You can concatenate groups in the above mentioned command by using `,` to separate them. However groups like `sambashare` might not be needed if you not have samba installed.

```
usermod -aG <group1>, <group2> <username>
```

Comment: Thanks - What does it essentially do? Do I need to do it for every user I create? I'd be happy if you can add some details